# Append a function and its arguments to a list without calling the function immediately

Tags: python, function

I want to do something like this:

```py
lst = []
lst.append( func1(a, b, c, d) ) # do NOT execute function here/now
lst.append( func2(e, f) )       # do NOT execute function here/now
lst.append( func3(w, x, y) )    # do NOT execute function here/now

# ... later
for f in lst:
    result = f # execute function here/now
```

What is the simplest way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: I'm curious: *Why* do you want to delay the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.append( functools.partial(func1, a, b, c, d) )
```

Comment: What if I am getting: 'functools.partial' object is not subscriptable ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `func(*args)` syntax to provide a tuple of positional arguments:

```py
lst = []
lst.append( (func1, a, b, c, d) )
lst.append( (func2, e, f) )
lst.append( (func3, w, x, y) )

for func, *args in lst:
    result = func(*args)
```

Alternatively, just guard each function call with a lambda:

```py
lst = []
lst.append(lambda: func1(a, b, c, d))
lst.append(lambda: func2(e, f))
lst.append(lambda: func3(w, x, y))

for f in lst:
    result = f()
```

The second version is subject to some subtle bugs, because the argument names (e.g. `a`) aren't evaluated when the lambda is created, they're evaluated when the lambda is *called* - this means if `a` changes between the `append` and the call, these two solutions will give different results, and the first one is probably what you intended. So I'd recommend avoiding the second one, unless the arguments are just constants.

Comment: Well, of course, you can do the second approach without that issue, straightforwardly, `lambda a, b, c : lambda: func1(a, b, c, d)(a,b,c)` or use `partial`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or `lambda a=a, b=b, c=c: func1(a, b, c)`, since the argument defaults are evaluated immediately.  But either way, it requires writing each argument name twice.

Comment: Sure, although, personally I don't like that idiom, having default parameters that are never intended to be used ... although maybe in this case it isn't so weird

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't be surprised if they *want* to evaluate the argument names at call-time, *because* they might change. Seems like a possible reason for not wanting to execute right away in the first place.

Comment: @HeapOverflow It's possible, but usually (in my experience at least) that's not what you need. A common pitfall is when you're creating callback functions in a loop, and they all end up using the arguments for the last one, because of late binding of the argument names.